# Handling a swipe effect (flex AIR) with extra functionality

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flex-mobile

I have some text content in a scrollable container and I want the user to be able to scroll it having the nice effect of it moving according to the swipe velocity and to keep scrolling until the user taps it. (as many applications for mobile touch screens).

I am thinking to combine events to do it. I will catch the swipe to know the direction, have mouse in and out to see velocity and legth of the swipe, and then keep scrolling with a proportional velocity and length until the user taps the screen.

Does my idea makes sense? (I don´t want to do the work and find out it was really simple and I just didn{t knew how)

Thanks in advance

Maria

Comment: What apps continue to scroll until the user taps to stop? Doesn't the Flex List w/ the Mobile Skin already scroll based on swipe velocity?

Comment: For example, the columns on TweetDeck for Android. They keep rolling until you tap them. Its quite usefull in that particular application...

Comment: I can't replicate that. I just tried TweetDeck on my LG Optimus V and my Xoom.  The "scrolling" stops on it's own accord after a swipe [or when it reaches the top or bottom of a list].  If I want it to scroll immediately to the top I have to hit the home button and it will scroll non-stop until hitting the top or I tap to stop.

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy Tab and works as explained. Saw that the Adobe documentation refers as this as the spring effect... Maybe that helps...

Comment: I just tested on my Galaxy Tab (7 inch).  After a swipe on Tweetdeck; the column stops moving on it's own.  What documentation are you reading?  Can you provide a link?  I would expect the "Spring" effect would refer to the bounce that happens when you get to the top or bottom of a list.

Comment: Yes, the Tweetdeck columns slow down and stop eventualy. The user can stop them early by tapping it. I wanted to create that on a long text screen.

Comment: What is a "Long Text Screen"?  Do you mean a list?  Or a TextInput?  or a TextArea?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A scroller will achieve this for you:

```
<s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:VGroup>
            <!-- Your content e.g. -->
                <s:TextInput/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Click the screen and drag in the direction. Tap to stop the movement or wait till it ends.

Comment: I cant seem to make it work. Do I have to handle any events, or will the component do it for me?

Comment: apologies, I miss-read the question. I didn't understand that you wanted the scrolling to keep going until you clicked it. The above code will move when you swipe but wont keep going... my mistake.